# JS autofill in form, textboxes clearing on focus?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to autofill in a form via javascript. Now, the issue I am having is when I focus on another textbox after these have been filled out, all the ones I filled in clear and empty their textboxes? Can someone tell me why its doing this and how I am get passed it.

JS:

```
window.setTimeout(function () { 
    document.getElementsByClassName("_ph6vk _623pz _o716c")[0].focus(); 
}, 1000); 

window.setTimeout(function () { 
    document.getElementsByClassName("_ph6vk _623pz _o716c")[0].value = "some value 0";
}, 2000); 

window.setTimeout(function () { 
    document.getElementsByClassName("_ph6vk _623pz _o716c")[1].focus(); 
}, 3000); 

window.setTimeout(function () { 
    document.getElementsByClassName("_ph6vk _623pz _o716c")[1].value = "some value 2";
}, 4000);
```

HTML:

```
<form class="_asaim">
    <div class="_fhskl">
        <div class="_j5suk"></div>
        <div class="_hxmdu">
            or
        </div>
        <div class="_j5suk"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="_agqzm">
        <div class="_sjplo _8ki4j">
            <input aria-describedby="" aria-label="Mobile Number or Email" aria-required="true" class="_ph6vk _623pz _o716c" name="emailOrPhone" placeholder="Mobile Number or Email" type="text" value="d">
            <div class="_gaby6">
                <span class="coreSpriteInputError _eyp7r"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="_agqzm">
        <div class="_sjplo _8ki4j">
            <input aria-describedby="" aria-label="Full Name" aria-required="false" class="_ph6vk _623pz _o716c" name="fullName" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" value="d">
            <div class="_gaby6">
                <span class="coreSpriteInputAccepted _eyp7r"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="_agqzm">
        <div class="_sjplo _8ki4j">
            <input aria-describedby="" aria-label="Username" aria-required="true" class="_ph6vk _623pz _o716c" maxlength="30" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" value="d">
            <div class="_gaby6">
                <span class="coreSpriteInputError _eyp7r"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="_agqzm">
        <div class="_sjplo _8ki4j">
            <input aria-describedby="" aria-label="Password" aria-required="true" class="_ph6vk _623pz _o716c" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" value="d">
            <div class="_gaby6">
                <span class="coreSpriteInputError _eyp7r"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="_9mno0 _ov9ai"><button class="_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0"><span class="_9mno0 _ov9ai">Sign up</span></button></span>
    </div>
    <p class="_fd2m9"><!-- react-text: 144 -->By signing up, you agree to our <!-- /react-text --><a class="_nzfks" href="/legal/terms/" target="_blank">Terms</a><!-- react-text: 146 --> &amp; <!-- /react-text --><a class="_nzfks" href="/legal/privacy/" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a><!-- react-text: 148 -->.<!-- /react-text --></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell without seeing all of your code, however the code you've posted is simply setting values on your inputs after a certain time has elapsed (the no. of milliseconds you specify in your setTimeout function), so I suspect you're doing something that causes these timeout functions to be called, which overwrites the inputs. I'm guessing the reason the input are being *cleared* is that maybe the value e.g. "some value 0" doesn't actually exist as a 'value' for the relevant input, so instead the input just gets cleared, as the specified value can't be found? I can't be completely sure unless you post your full code.